# Integration over a set defined using inequalities

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, self-learning

I was hoping to get some help in understanding the solution provided below. I understand that the integral will evaluate to $\frac{1}{n!}$, however, my uncertainty lies in how the integral is setup. I am not sure how we use $C$ to setup the integrands. Why would it not be $${\int_0^1 \int_0^{x_n} \dotsb \int_0^{x_3} \int_0^{x_2} \int_0^{x_1}} ds_1 ds_2 \dotsc ds_n?$$.
Let $C$ be a set in $n$-dimensional space and let

$$Q(C) = \underset{C}{\int\!\!\dotsb\!\!\int} dx_1 dx_2 \dotsc dx_n.$$

If $C = \{(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n) : 0 \le x_1 \le x_2 \le \dotsb \le x_n \le 1  \}$, then

$$Q(C) = {\int_0^1 \int_0^{x_n} \dotsb \int_0^{x_3} \int_0^{x_2}} dx_1 dx_2 \dotsc dx_n = \frac{1}{n!}.$$

Comment: @PeterForeman, thank you - I see that, however, I still don't understand why we would exclude $x_1$ from the integrand. Could you explain why we would do that?

Comment: We don't exclude it from the integrand. As shown in the answer it varies from $0$ to $x_2$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson no it does not, I am still having a hard time understanding why we set the bounds excluding x_1, thank you though. Do you know what the name of this particular topic is in calculus?

Comment: @nwaldo The answer clearly includes the differential $dx_1$ corresponding to the bound $\int_0^{x_2}$. This implies that $0\le x_1\le x_2$ for each value of $x_2$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, Thank you for your help, I found a post that helped me identify a way to determine the limits of integration -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295032/int-0xyzw1-left-fracxy-right-left-fracyz-right-left